# PowerShell Will Not Set Processor Affinity

Tags: powershell

Using the following code powershell won't set processor affinity, but, sets idle just fine?

```bsh
    $ffproc = Start-Process -filepath $ffm -ArgumentList $aaa -NoNewWindow -PassThru

    $ff2 = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessById( $ffproc.Id )
    $ff2.PriorityClass = 'Idle'
    $ff2.ProcessorAffinity = 0x7

    Wait-Process -inputObject $ffproc
```

Comment: What cores are you assigning? eg. CPU1 (0001) + CPU3 (0100) = 5 (0101). So `$ff2.ProcessorAffinity = 5`
After looking, it appears you want CPU1+2+3? Just change your Hex code from `0x7` to decimal `7`

Comment: Tried using `7` instead `0x7` still uses all cores. Have been checking with `(get-process -name ffmpeg).ProcessorAffinity` and process explorer. Yes I'm aiming for cores 1+2+3 out of six cores.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with your `$ffproc` variable. What does `$ff2` show when called?
Running this on my system shows the reduction in core usage.